# Looking to find out how to power 2x 12v, 0.2amp, 3pin computer fans through an arduino uno

Tags: arduino, power-supply

I'm fairly new to using Arduino boards. I'm trying to make a fan controller for two 3-pin fans that run on 12V at 0.2 amp. I read that all I need is a power supply that will run at 12V and #of_fans * the amp of each of them, so in this case 0.4 amp. I'm having trouble finding a power supply that would work in this case and I'm confused how I would use it. Would I be running the power supply through the arduino, or would that damage the board?

Thank you.

Comment: 3 pin fans aren't really subject to control, if you want to change their speed your only option is messing with the supply voltage.

Comment: Power the fan's, but **do not** involve the Arduino.  **Do not** run the power for them through it.  If you want to turn them on and off, study the schematic of 3d printers or even get an Arduino-based printer board instead of an Arduino.

Comment: I already knew that I would have to change the voltage, I would be looking into how to do that with the arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Although computer cooling fans draw low current, you can not feed them directly with Arduino. Typically, you need a buck or buck-boost converter that can be controlled by Arduino to change the input voltage of the cooling fans. But, you can simply use a ULN2803 L293, or L298 to control the fans by PWM. The speed of the fans is controlled by the duty cycle of the PWM. Don't forget to add a free-wheeling diode and maybe a capacitor to the output.

Good luck